# Continuity of Probability Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, continuity

Assume that $F,G$ are absolutely continuous and strictly increasing distribution functions on $[0,1]$, and let $\bar{F}(x)=1-F(x)$. Consider the function $H(x) := \bar{F}(x)-G(x)$. Then, there exists a unique $x^*\in(0,1)$ such that $H(x^*)=\bar{F}(x^*)-G(x^*)=0$. Accordingly, there exists another function $K(x)$, so that $$H(x)=(x-x^*)\cdot K(x).$$
Can we conclude that $\lim_{x\to x^*} K(x) <+\infty$ or that $K(x)$ is also continuous?

*My effort*: by plotting the function $H(x)$ for various distributions (e.g., different Beta distributions on $[0,1]$), it seems that this should be the case, i.e., $K(x)$ cannot explode as $x$ tends to $x^*$. However, I cannot think of a rigorous argument.

Comment: If $H$ were differentiable at $x^*$ you could use L’Hopital’s rule.

Comment: K(x) seems to act as a "derivative" of $H$ around $x^*$ (check with overkill assumptions on regularity) I think you may consider using very basic theorems of real analysis on $H$ e.g. Rolle or something like that...

Comment: @Michael Yes, $H$ is continuously differentiable everywhere. So, you mean to write $$\lim_{x\to x^*}K(x)=\lim_{x\to x^*}\frac{H(x)}{x-x^*}\overset{\text{L'Hopital}}{=}\lim_{x\to x^*}H'(x)= H'(x^*)<\infty.$$

Comment: Why is $H$ continuously differentiable everywhere?

Comment: If you define $F(x)=G(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as piecewise linear with $F(1/2)=1/2$, and with $x=1/2$ being a sharp (nondifferentiable) point where the slope changes, then you can make the left limit of $H(x)/(x-1/2)$ different from the right limit.  Say, for example, $F(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ and then $F(x)$ changes slope to $1/2$ during $x \in (1/2,3/4)$, then changes slope again to achieve $F(1)=1$.  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1/2^-}\frac{1-2F(x)}{x-1/2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow1/2^-}\frac{1-2x}{x-1/2} = -2$$

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the example! I see it now. So, one needs to assume that $F,G$ are differentiable. So, under the current assumptions, it may still hold that $K$ explodes at $x^*$.

Comment: My example above was for when $H(x)/(x-x^*)$ has a finite left limit at $x=x^*$, and a finite right limit, but the two are not equal. So the left-limit is $-2$ but the right-limit will be something else.